# How to deal with paths on PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

What is the best practice approach to deal with paths to scripts/folders on PowerShell ?

Example 1 (relative to the target script location) :

```
$SettingsModule = (Get-Item -Path ('{0}\..\Settings\SettingsReader.psm1' -f $PSScriptRoot)).FullName
$AzureSqlUtilsModule = (Get-Item -Path ('{0}\UtilsSqlAzure.psm1' -f $PSScriptRoot)).FullName

# code here ...
```

Example 2 (path is informed via parameter):

```
$PfxPath = (Join-Path -Path $SecureRepoRoot -ChildPath $appCredentials.PfxPath)
# code here ...
```

Or should the common paths to my local folders/repositories/scripts be handle with `environment variables` ? Or is there a better alternative ?

I have a Linux background, and ideally I would use environment variables to define a common paths, however I'm not sure if this is a best approach on Windows/PowerShell.

Comment: Depends on what you are doing. I would go for relative paths as of powershells modularity. When you move or update a module, you give all relevant resources with it. I don't like external dependencies that much, so I stick with that approach. Env might not be present or vary on systems - the path of your module or script is always clear.

Comment: Good point @restless1987. If you make it as an answer I would be glad to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you are doing. I would go for relative paths as of powershells modularity. When you move or update a module, you give all relevant resources with it. I don't like external dependencies that much, so I stick with that approach. Env might not be present or vary on systems - the path of your module or script is always clear.